# How can I unit test a Joomla 1.5 or 1.6 module with PHPUnit?

Tags: phpunit, joomla1.5, joomla1.6

I can not find a tutorial on the subject. Before running the unit test, the Joomla framework must be loaded ... A code example would be welcome, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for the official **[Joomla Unit Testing Documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/Unit_Testing)** - It contains example tests and more stuff to help you getting started.

Comment: Thanks. I found that in the doc: 

Why can't I use "phpunit testname.php" to run my tests?

The test facility has to do some work to be able to load the "Joomla!" framework and to be able to inject mock classes. It's difficult to do this from the PHPUnit test runner, so we built our own. Also, the Joomla test runner has specific options designed to make it easy to select specific tests. Over time we will add more functionality to the test runner so it has many of the capabilities of the phpunit command.

Comment: There is a thing called [`bootstrap`](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html) in PHPUnit which might be interesting for your own test-suite. Additionally you can put [a default configuration into an XML file](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.3/en/appendixes.configuration.html). If you can solve the integration issues with these methods I would favour them over a self-written cli-runner at first. However if the joomla uses it's own test runner then this is needed for their suite.