# Unit tests to develop Joomla components

Tags: php, unit-testing, joomla

I'm developing components for Joomla! and want to know if there is a framework that can be used in a simple way to perform unit tests for these components.

Thanks for your attention.

Greetings!

Comment: See also [How can I unit test a Joomla 1.5 or 1.6 module with PHPUnit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559553/how-can-i-unit-test-a-joomla-1-5-or-1-6-module-with-phpunit/6571821).

Comment: Will be interesting to set up a continuous integration server to perform test on Joomla projects developed?

Comment: Sounds like you should do so, yes. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PHPUnit](http://phpunit.de) is probably the first framework that comes to mind when thinking about unit testing in PHP. As far as I see, Joomla itself is already using it.

Some useful links:

- http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_create_a_continuous_integration (a bit broader than unit test only).
- http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2177431
- http://docs.joomla.org/Running_Automated_Tests_for_Version_1.6

Hope that helps,